# How to handle a post-save signal for an M2M relationship with model inheritance in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-signals

The question title is quite the sentence, but hopefully the code below will clear it up:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...


class AbstractParent(models.Model):
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(
        Foo,
        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related'
    )

    def bar(self):
        ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ChildOne(AbstractParent):
    ...


class ChildTwo(AbstractParent):
    ...
```

Lets say that my app's label is 'myapp'.

Basically, the base class of the `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` has a M2M to the class `Foo`. What I want to do is this: whenever an object of the `Foo` class is saved, I want to call the `bar()` method of all the objects of `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` which has a relation to the `Foo` object through the `foos` field. To do this, I tried writing a simple signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def call_bar_for_all_related_objects_to_foo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Do the thing
```

At this point, Im kinda lost. How do I query all the children classes of the `AbstractParent` class and call their `bar()` methods whenever there is a relation to the `instance` in the signal? Ideally, I want to query my database only once, and in one query, I want to get all the objects of `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` related to the `instance` in the signal. Please note, in my actual models, there are more than two child classes of the `AbstractParent`, so an answer that keeps that in mind is appreciated. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't satisfy your single query requirement, but here's a way to at least get the job done with a query per child class:

```
def call_bar_for_all_related_objects_to_foo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for field in instance._meta.get_fields():
        if not field.related_model:
            continue
        if not issubclass(field.related_model, AbstractParent):
            continue
        for related_object in getattr(instance, field.related_name).all():
            related_object.bar()
```

#### Single query update

I don't think this can be done in a single query in a general way like this.  The only way I know to get whole related django objects out of a single query is via `select_related`, which doesn't work with `ManyToMany` relationships.

If a single query is important, implementation will probably require more specific details on `.bar()`, which would likely need to be refactored into a class method that works on the results of a `.values()` call or something.

Comment: Any way to make this execute in one db query?

Comment: updated with more details, but short answer: not that I know of

Comment: Fair enough. It is a complicated issue, and this is the best implementation that I know of. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but after testing the code, I get the following error: TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable, in the line `for related_object in getattr(instance, field.related_name):`

Comment: sorry, I left off `.all()` to make the queryset iterable.  Fixed now.